# GlassFish 4.0 w/ Jersey returns 500 internal server error without exception

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey-2.0

I'm using a GlassFish 4.0 server and server-sided JPA-based classes, which I want to deliver via JAX-RS. This works fine so far for simple entities. However, if I have a @OneToMany relation for example AND there is a linked entity, the server returns a 500 internal server error. In that case, nothing is logged to the server log. In order to find the error, I created a small custom JSP page to get more info about what happened. The code is just this:

```
Status: <%= pageContext.getErrorData().getStatusCode() %>
Throwable: <%= pageContext.getErrorData().getThrowable() %>
```

Unfortunately, the output is just "Status: 500 Throwable: null"

My own server-sided code seems to run properly (did some debug output), but however, some error emerges. In this example, the User and Issue classes can be retrieved without a problem unless there is a linked IssueComment entity:

User class:

```
package my.application.model;

import static javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 * The persistent class for the User database table.
 * 
 */
@XmlRootElement
@Entity(name="User")
@Table(name="User")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="failedLogin")
    private short failedLogin;

    @Column(name="firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name="middlename")
    private String middlename;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to IssueComment
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch = LAZY)
    private List<IssueComment> issueComments;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to SignalComment
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch = LAZY)
    private List<SignalComment> signalComments;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to SignalMeasure
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch = LAZY)
    private List<SignalMeasure> signalMeasures;

    public User() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

         // more getters and setters auto-generated by Eclipse
        }
```

User class:

```
package my.application.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@NamedQuery(
    name = "getSingleIssue",
    query = "SELECT i FROM Issue i WHERE i.id = :id"
)
/**
 * The persistent class for the Issue database table.
 * 
 */
@XmlRootElement
@Entity(name="Issue")
@Table(name="Issue")
public class Issue implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="concernedModule")
    private String concernedModule;

    @Column(name="createdate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdate;

    @Column(name="duedate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date duedate;

    @Column(name="priority")
    private int priority;

    @Column(name="reminderdate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date reminderdate;

    @Column(name="responsibleUserId")
    private int responsibleUserId;

    @Column(name="sendingModule")
    private String sendingModule;

    @Column(name="severity")
    private int severity;

    @Column(name="status")
    private int status;

    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;

    // bidirectional many-to-one association to IssueComment
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "issue")
    private List<IssueComment> issueComments;

    public Issue() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

 // more getters and setters....
}
```

IssueComment:

```
package my.application.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.util.Date;


/**
 * The persistent class for the IssueComment database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity(name="IssueComment")
@Table(name="IssueComment")
public class IssueComment implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Lob
    @Column(name="comment")
    private String comment;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="time")
    private Date time;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Issue
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="issueId")
    private Issue issue;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="userId")
    private User user;

    public IssueComment() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

 // getters/setters....
}
```

The Webservice is as follows:

```
package my.application.server.webservice;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

import my.application.data.UserStorage;
import my.application.logger.Logger;
import my.application.model.Signal;
import my.application.model.SignalComment;
import my.application.model.User;

@Provider
@Path("User")
public class UserService extends ResourceConfig {

    private UserStorage storage = new UserStorage();

    public UserService() {
        this.packages("my.application.model");
    }

    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Path("load")
    @GET
    public User getUser(@QueryParam("id") int id) {
        try {
            Logger.getInstance().log("fetching id: " + id);
            User u = storage.getUser(id);
            Logger.getInstance().log("number of signal comments: " + u.getSignalComments().size());
            SignalComment sc = u.getSignalComments().get(0);
            Logger.getInstance().log("Signal 0 comment: " + sc.getComment());
            Signal s = sc.getSignal();
            Logger.getInstance().log("Signal subject: " + s.getSubject());
            return u;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // this code is not being reached (so no errors in this method):
        Logger.getInstance().log("---EXCEPTION HAS BEEN THROWN---");

        return null;
    }
}
```

I left away the client source code since it's server-sided and can be reproduced with a normal browser, so no necessity for client code here IMHO.

Comment: Seems like a null pointer exception. Can you debug?

Comment: Do you have Development mode turned on in your web.xml?

Comment: @Sotirios: Unfortunately not - when I try to set the logging to FINEST or to start the server in debug mode, Eclipse is getting a TimeOutException when trying to launch the GlassFish. I'll try out development mode. It's currently not turned on.

Comment: @unwichtich: I turned on development mode via context-param in web.xml, but I'm still not seeing any errors about that in the server log file.

Comment: @grobmotoriker Do you see any of your logs being logged into the server log?

Comment: @michal: yep, the output of the Logger class is being logged. Normally, Exceptions are also logged. Also, the last call to the Logger "Signal subject" is basically the second-last server-side command in my code and is being logged. Something seems to go wrong at the return statement (or better: *after* the return statement...) which triggers a 500 error, but for some reason there's no throwable to process. I guess, that's why no Exception can be logged. Pretty weird however.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you don't have any cyclic references in graph (objects) you're trying to marshall to XML. For example, this could cause a problem:

```
User -> IssueComment -> (the same) User
```

or

```
User -> IssueComment -> Issue -> IssueComment -> (the same) User
```

Such structures cannot be marshalled into XML.

**Note:** Add `@XmlRootElement` annotation to `IssueComment` (I think it's not needed but it's better to have it there).

**Note:** We know about the logging issue and it will be solved as a part of [JERSEY-2000](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2000).

Comment: That's it! Thanks alot for the info, also for the info about the logging issue. I've annotated the attributes (for that example, the user and issue attribute in IssueComment) with @XmlTransient so they are not taken into account when marshalling the object.

Comment: Additional info: if one is experiencing that problem - not attributes, but the getter methods should be annotated with @XmlTransient